# Question on clustered and non clustered index

Tags: sql-server

I have only two columns on a table, on column1 I applied clustered index and on column2 I applied a non clustered index but when I enter values into a table why is that column2 values are sorted rather than column1 if clustered is going to sort the data that should only sort column1, not column2? - SQL server 2012

Comment: A table is logically an unordered set of rows. You need to specify an `ORDER BY` clause if you need data returned in a particular order. Without it, SQL Server may return data in whatever order it chooses, which may or may not be in index order.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it in this way: a clustered index IS the data. So in your example your data is sorted on column1 by default because you applied a clustered index on column1.

Comment: This is not correct. Data will often be sorted by the clustered index with a select statement but only on small tables. Once you get to a certain point it won't sort anymore. And it only does it by accident in the first place. There is one and only one way to order data reliably, with an order by clause.